# Change tikz coordinate depending on variable

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can define a coordinate which depend on a variable ( coordinate change automatically when variable change )

Here an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\def\border{2cm}
\coordinate (A) at ([shift={(\border,\border)}]current page.south west);
\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(-\border,-\border)}]current page.north east);
\draw[thick,rounded corners] (A) rectangle (B);
\def\border{1cm}
%\coordinate (A) at ([shift={(\border,\border)}]current page.south west);
%\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(-\border,-\border)}]current page.north east);
\draw[thick,rounded corners,double,red] (A) rectangle (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like if there a method to modify coordinates `A` and `B` when `\border` change  without redefining those coordinates every time.

Comment: node names are global so definitions won't work backwards. You can instead make a key with `/.code` that defines (A) and (B) everytime it is invoked with it's argument #1 replacing the `\border`.

Comment: @percusse can you add an answer to clarify your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[put ab/.code={%
\coordinate (A) at ([shift={(#1,#1)}]current page.south west);%
\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(-#1,-#1)}]current page.north east);%
}]
\draw[thick,rounded corners,put ab=2cm] (A) rectangle (B);
% only need to use put ab when you want to change a b otherwise they will remain
\draw[thick,rounded corners,put ab=1cm] (A) rectangle (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```